# 301 redirect for a multistore with different domains

Tags: .htaccess

i have set up many 301 redirects like this:

```
Redirect 301 /impressum http://mydomain.de/imprint
```

the problem is, i am running a magent multistore. now it redirects every domain, which leads to 404 errors.
how can i limit the redirection to a certain domain?

```
Redirect 301 http://mydomain.de/impressum   http://mydomain.de/imprint
```

does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using mod_rewrite instead so you can match against a hostname:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^impressum(.*)$ http://mydomain.de/imprint$1 [L,R=301]
```